# Как правильно подать строки для лемматизации?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, pymorphy2

Провел токеннизацию большого текста, теперь пытаюсь подать эти строки на проведение лемматизации. Лемматизацию провожу с помощью pymorphy2, библиотека принимает только слово. Не могу понять как подать предложение по слову, но так чтобы он сохранил мне все в dataframe так же по предложениям.

```
data_clear = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\ugrobug\\Desktop\\out_token.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')

def lemma(data_clear):
    morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
    final_data = pd.DataFrame({'Question'})

    for i in data_clear['0']:
        c = morph.parse(i)[0]
        lemmas = c.normal_form
        print(lemmas)
    final_data.loc[len(final_data)]=[lemmas]

    final_data.to_csv('C:\\Users\\ugrobug\\Desktop\\out_lemma.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')

lemma(data_clear)
```

Comment: Если коротко - разбить строку на слова, лемматизировать в цикле каждое слово отдельно, собрать обратно в предложение.

Comment: @Евгений, [что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize, regexp_tokenize
from pymorphy2 import MorphAnalyzer

def tokenize_n_normalize(sent, pat=r"(?u)\b\w\w+\b", morph=MorphAnalyzer()):
    return [morph.parse(tok)[0].normal_form 
            for tok in regexp_tokenize(sent, pat)]


text = """Провел токеннизацию большого текста, теперь пытаюсь подать эти строки на проведение лемматизации. Лемматизацию провожу с помощью pymorphy2, библиотека принимает только слово. Не могу понять как подать предложение по слову, но так чтобы он сохранил мне все в dataframe так же по предложениям."""

df = pd.DataFrame({
  "sent": [sent for sent in sent_tokenize(text)]
})

df["sent"] = df["sent"].map(lambda x: " ".join(tokenize_n_normalize(x)))
```

**результат:**

```
In [22]: df
Out[22]:
                                                                                                  sent
0    провести токеннизация большой текст теперь пытаться подать этот строка на проведение лемматизация
1                            лемматизация провозить помощь pymorphy2 библиотека принимать только слово
2  не мочь понять как подать предложение по слово но так чтобы он сохранить я весь dataframe так же...
```